# Any concise way of using `regex` to reverse a string, e.g., with `gsub` in R? (looking for workarounds)

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I know we are able to do it using other `non-regex` ways ***more efficiently***, e.g., `rev` + `strsplit` or `rev` + `substring`, but I wonder if we can accomplish it with regex only.

---

For example, assuming we have a string `s1 <- "ab82m4"`,  my `gsub` attempt is

```
> gsub(strrep("(.)", nchar(s1)), paste0(sprintf("\\%d", nchar(s1):1), collapse = ""), s1)
[1] "4m28ba"
```

which works well but cumbersome.

However, when we have longer sting `s2 <- "ab82m42,x7"`, we cannot reach the desired output since the number of groups is more than `9`, which exceeds the upper limit allowed by `gsub` (I guess)

```
> gsub(strrep("(.)", nchar(s2)), paste0(sprintf("\\%d", nchar(s2):1), collapse = ""), s2)
[1] "a0x,24m28ba" # should be "7x,24m28ba"
```

---

I am just wondering if there is a pattern or workaround that we can apply `gsub` for reversing the string. Curious about the possibility, indeed! :)

---

## Emphasis

I am curious about the ***possible workarounds*** (instead of grouping) to achieve the goal, i.e., reversing the string in a regex way, not ***discussing the feasibility of using grouping here***.

Comment: The nature of this question might fit in better at the [Codegolf stack exchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)--it could get more attention there. Regex being somewhat universal, you might also be able to frame the question to not restrict to R's implementation of `gsub`.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks, good point! Yes, I would say `sort of` codegolf objective, but I was wondering if `gsub` can make it in another way (based on some known limitations by `gsub`).

Comment: On codegolf you could restrict it to regex find/replace functions--even with the limits of R's `gsub` imposed on more flexible functions in other languages. They're all about coding under more-or-less arbitrary restrictions! And they're also very clever at finding solutions under such restrictions.

Comment: There is a dedicated function for this in stringi: `stringi::stri_reverse(s2)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the GNU sed manual there is an example of regex-based reversal of strings: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Reverse-chars-of-lines

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f

/../! b

# Reverse a line.  Begin embedding the line between two newlines
s/^.*$/\
&\
/

# Move first character at the end.  The regexp matches until
# there are zero or one characters between the markers
tx
:x
s/\(\n.\)\(.*\)\(.\n\)/\3\2\1/
tx

# Remove the newline markers
s/\n//g
```

Perhaps you could implement this approach in R? These are my attempts, but I'm sure they can be improved / less cumbersome:

```r
s2 <- "ab82m42,x7"
# Add a 'marker' (tilde) to the start and end of the string
s3 <- gsub("(.*)", "~\\1~", s2)
# Swap the front and rear characters repeatedly
replicate(nchar(s2) / 2, s3 <<- gsub("(~.)(.*)(.~)", "\\3\\2\\1", s3))
#> [1] "7~b82m42,x~a" "7x~82m42,~ba" "7x,~2m42~8ba" "7x,2~m4~28ba" "7x,24~~m28ba"
# Remove the tildes
gsub("~", "", s3)
#> [1] "7x,24m28ba"
```

```r
# Using a repeat (while(TRUE)) loop
s2 <- "ab82m42,x7"
s3 <- gsub("(.*)", "~\\1~", s2)
repeat{s3 <<- gsub("(~.)(.*)(.~)", "\\3\\2\\1", s3); if(grepl("~~|~.~", s3)) break}
gsub("~", "", s3)
#> [1] "7x,24m28ba"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>